# Wi-Fi problems Acer Aspire e15 E5-575G-53VG Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, acer, atheros

I've been having this wifi problem on my Qualcomm Atheros for a very long time and have looked for solutions everywhere, I've tried wicd, updating my driver from kvalo, etc..

I have though ran `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k` and get this error:

```
Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
```

Please I really need help, my wireless-info will be found below

http://pastebin.com/BvxSbGCb

Edit: Forgot to mention this is a dual boot system along with windows 10

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of your “wireless problem”? According to the wireless info log the wireless driver was able to associate itself with an access point.

Comment: Problem consists of wireless constantly disconnecting and sometimes not connecting at all, also its connection is insanely slow compared to my windows 10 (laptop is dual booted)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify that? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we notice this:

> Group Cipher : TKIP

Not only is TKIP rather insecure, many Linux drivers do not connect well with TKIP. Check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, we see that your device is attempting to roam between two networks with the same name, "ea2700". I suspect that they are the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz bands of your router. I suggest that you rename one, or both, to something like ea2700-2.4 and ea2700-5. Ask your device to connect to one and it will likely stay. At least in my neighborhood, 5 gHz is rare, so I'd make that my first choice.

We also notice that you have both Network Manager and Wicd installed and running. I suggest that you remove Wicd which is, as you've seen, doing no better job that NM:

```
 sudo apt-get purge wicd
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking your time to help me resolve my issue it really means a lot. I've applied all your changes and can already see a definitive speed increase in my wi-fi since i am using my 5mHz band now. As for the constant disconnecting issue I will see if it occurs tonight and if nothing goes bad I will accept your answer tomorrow! Thanks